# ob_start() prints without any flush function

Tags: php

I am just learning PHP. In the PHP site they said `ob_start()` will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer.

```
    <?php

    if(ob_start()){
    echo "output buffer started\n";


    echo 'hello';

    $bufferdata = ob_get_contents();//with and without function...


    }
```

But the above script prints

> output buffer started hello

Why does this happen?

Comment: If outbut buffering is still active when the script ends, PHP outputs it automatically. In effect, every script ends with `ob_end_flush()`.

Comment: @Mark Baker Thank you bro ....